# Google App engine Firebase import error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, firebase, webapp2

I am working on a project in which i want to use firebase in webapp2 python. I created the lib folder in root directory of the project for using the third party library. Then i imported the firebase admin and it is give following error,s on import. Please help me where i am doing the mistake, Thanks

**Imports:**

```
import firebase_admin
import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.id_token
from firebase_admin import auth
from firebase_admin import credentials
```

**Log:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "D:\Work\Bolt Reactor\Final Website Production\kompassera\Routes.py", line 5, in <module>
    from controllers import Home, Signup, Login, Profile, Listing, Classroom, Search, Enrollment, Firebase
  File "D:\Work\Bolt Reactor\Final Website Production\kompassera\controllers\Signup.py", line 5, in <module>
    import firebase_admin
  File "D:\Work\Bolt Reactor\Final Website Production\kompassera\lib\firebase_admin\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from firebase_admin import credentials
  File "D:\Work\Bolt Reactor\Final Website Production\kompassera\lib\firebase_admin\credentials.py", line 20, in <module>
    import google.auth
ImportError: No module named auth
```

Comment: It looks like `google-auth` is missing. How did you install `firebase_admin` module? When I run `pip install firebase_admin`, I get all the dependencies including `google-auth` installed. I tried your example and it worked that way.

Comment: I installed the library by navigating to C:\python27\Scripts and running pip install firebase_admin. then I also copied it to my project's lib folder from site-packages folder.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It seems to be because of a naming collision with the google-auth and GAE packages. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @BrandonVeber I solved this problem and I have answered my question. If it seems useful to you then hit upvote to both question and answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation

```
import google.auth.transport.requests
```

above line will look for the Google package in pythons default directory in on every machine this behaviour can be different depending on where i is going to look for the installed packages.

Solution:
 make a lib directory on the root of your project and place the google package in this lib directory, then add ____inti____.py in this lib folder and amend your imports like this

```
import lib.firebase_admin
import lib.google.auth.transport.requests
import lib.google.oauth2.id_token
from lib.firebase_admin import auth
from lib.firebase_admin import credentials
```